# find path directory in sub directory

Tags: linux, find, aix, hp-ux

I want to find the path for directory name `bbb` where the parent directory called `aaa`

For example

```
/aaa/bbb
/tmp/aaa/bbb
/usr/bin/aaa/bbb
/home/aaa/bbb
/home/aaa/xxx/bbb
```

So i wrote something like this:

```
find /*/aaa -name bbb
```

In some platforms it works and in some it doesn't, and in any case the `/aaa/bbb` is not found because there is no parent directory to `aaa`

I guess I could run `find / -name bbb | grep \/aaa` but I think if there is something smarter..?

Comment: many systems have the `locate` command implemented which nightly keeps a database of all filenames. you can then just `locate aaa/bbb`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-path` option for this case:

```
find / -type d  -path '*/aaa/bbb'
```

From the man page for find:

> File name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do not treat `/` or `.` specially; so, for example,

```
find . -path "./sr*sc"
```

> will print an entry for a directory called `./src/misc' (if one exists).

### Cross-Platform Compatibility

*Edit:* I just noticed the [aix](/questions/tagged/aix) and [hp-ux](/questions/tagged/hp-ux) tags.

You don’t specify which version of `find` you’re using and the above
information applies to GNU find. However, the man page also specifies that,

> The predicate -path is  also  supported by HP-UX find and will be in a forthcoming version of the POSIX standard.

so it looks like `-path` can be used in HP-UX but not with AIX (at least [not AIX 7.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm), the latest release as of 2015-08-24).

Comment: Not working. Return nothing.

Comment: @nir There was a typo in my find command where it was missing its directory argument, `/`. I've fixed that now.  I also added the ` -type d` argument to only provide the path to the directory itself and not files contained within it.

Comment: I dont know which version of `find` I have. This code works in linux abut in AIX I get `-path is not a valid option.`

Comment: `-path` is POSIX but was recently (issue 7, susv4, 2008) added to the standard.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer for future searches, but as my main platform is AIX it's not very helpful and I don't see better solution than my `find` + `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

/*/aaa does not match /aaa and this is the reason why find cannot find /aaa/bbb

If you don't like to start the find at / and if you don't have a recent find like the portable sfind that supports -path you need a better manual start list.